# Best way to store ARM template in GIT

Tags: git, azure, azure-resource-manager

My team has an ARM template (that contains a set of Azure Resources) we provide to customers to deploy a set of pre-configured resources in their Azure Subscription.

I would like to check this ARM template into version control (GIT) so we can leverage normal version control benefits.

What is the best way to do this? When I exported the ARM template from Azure I got one big JSON file, which I checked into GIT. The problem is, this is not very easy to develop or make changes to. My ARM template contains a few Azure Functions, and the code for these functions are all on one line of the JSON file (not readable).

What is the best flow for development of ARM template? Should I ask my devs to import the JSON into Azure, make their changes, then export the updated ARM template (with their changes) and check that into GIT?

Answer (score 2):

You can look into nested templates, so you have one big master template that stays relatively static and nested templates for each\several individuals to work on. That would reduce "noise" from other persons work.

As for the functions you can setup code integration with github, that will free your template from the function code (so separate configuration and code). This should be a much better development experience.